# Batch File what copy one file and rename it in Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i cant figure out this. I need to fill my whole storage.

So what i want?

I need to copy one single .iso file to e:\whatever (i can do that).
But then i got stuck cuz i dont know how to loop it with ren command like this:

```
copy C:\.iso E:\.whatever
ren specific.iso specific1.iso
```

and do it again but next time i want `specific2.iso`, `specific3.iso` and so on.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What have you tried? I think you need to start here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why it matters when it is not working..

Comment: That is just how it works, this is not a script writing service. We help each other with issues. So post your code, then we can help you see where you have gone wrong. See the link I sent.

Comment: Itt is expected from you to do research first. I think you found some keywords like batch-file and loop, whats missing is count. I'm shure googling will help.

Comment: Yea i am searching about two hours already. Thank you for your tip.

Comment: so post your code and we can try and help, easy as that.

Comment: What's your goal? Simulating "no(t enough) space on disk" or overwriting empty space for security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful, this will not stop until you kill it, or drive is full.
it will increment from 0 to infinity.

```
@echo off
set /a x=0
 :loop
 copy specific.iso specific%x%.iso
 set /a x+=1
 goto :loop
```

so you will end up having

`specific.iso
 specific0.iso
 specific1.iso
 specific2.iso`

etc.

if it is to copy multiple files you just write it accordingly, but that will copy each copy as well.

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
for /l %%I in (1,1,999) do (
    copy whatever.iso *%%I.iso
)
```

will create 999 copies of the file. Change 999 to a value that ensures your target disk is filled.

Something more creative could perhaps use a DO loop until the copy command produces an error (e.g., something like: DO UNTIL %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0), but I don't want to fill my disk to test :)

Comment: that will create 999 files called `whatever.iso1.iso` ...  `whatever.iso999.iso`

Comment: I understand how to create loop. I dont know how to rename copyied file each time i copy it and make it +1

Comment: @LukášVrábel You don't. You copy to a new location witha ne name. `@For /l %%# in (1,1,999) Do @Copy c:specific.iso E:\whatever\specific%%#.iso`

Comment: Sorry, I thought copying a file to multiple new files to fill your available storage was the goal. @GerhardBarnard, you are correct, the example should be "copy whatever.iso whatever%%I.iso"